# Using wildcards in conjunction with javascript split function

Tags: javascript

I would like to split a string using wildcards. I need to split my strings into substrings, where I find the following pattern ${1-9]$$127$. e.g. the split could be at "$1$$127$", "$2$$127$", "$3$$127$" etc.

I have attempted doing this using the following:

```
var myString = "$1$$127$$$3.25$$$$$$1$$127$$$3.25$$$$$$4$$185$$$3.12$$$$$";

myCount = (myString.split("$"+/[1-9]/+"$$127$").length - 1);
myArray = myString.split("$"+/[1-9]/+"$$127$");
```

However this does not seem to work.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two things at fault here.  Firstly, it looks like you're attempting to pass a regular expression to `split`, but you're actually constructing and passing a string, so it's going to split on exact matches of that.  Secondly, `$` is a special character in regular expressions, so it needs to be escaped.  Updated to use a regex, your code should be:

```
var myString = "$1$$127$$$3.25$$$$$$1$$127$$$3.25$$$$$$4$$185$$$3.12$$$$$";

myCount = (myString.split(/\$[1-9]\$\$127\$/).length - 1);
myArray = myString.split(/\$[1-9]\$\$127\$/);
```

Comment: There is an additional criteria to the above, which is where the split needs to be at "$3a$$127$". I've added this to the code, but it does not seem to be picking up: myString.split(/\$[1-9,3a]\$\$127\$/); Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Yes, my thoughts are that you should read up on how character sets/classes work in regexps, vs. alternations.